# Как удалить теги, в которых есть display:none?

Tags: php

````
    <span class="empname11">
        <a class="empname11" href="/users/Pls" title="Дмитрий Пренов">
            here string...
        </a>
        [
        <a class="empname11" href="/users/Pls" title="Pls">
            here string...
        </a>
        ]
    </span>
    <span id="po_date_83387313">
        here string...
    </span>
    <br/>
    <div id="po_comment_83387313">
        here string...
    </div>
    <div id="po_comment_original_83387313" style="display:none;">
        here string...
    </div>
</div>```
````

Comment: А что вы предлагаете, какие варианты вы нашли?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov если бы автор нашёл какие-то варианты, он, очевидно, не задал бы вопрос здесь

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6i5L3DGq  это так без регулярки) в коих не силён

Comment: @andreymal, то что очевидно вам - не очевидно мне, иначе я бы и не спрашивал. Мой подход к помощи - это возможность дать удочку и навыки ей пользоваться, а не саму рыбу.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov но при этом вы почему-то спрашиваете автора «какие удочки вы нашли», в то время как автор не знает, где их вообще искать

Comment: @andreymal, под удочкой я имею в виду не только методы решения этого конкретного вопроса (а они могут быть разными, от человека к человеку), но также и навыки использования сторонних инструментов вроде поиска, инструкций, руководств к использованию, и прочего.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov отправлять в гугл тем более запрещено :)

Comment: Обход дерева DOM с проверкой стиля текущей ноды. Вроде как уже давно сделали удобный API для стилей. А вот простого CSS -селектора на основе свойств стиля вроде нет. Даже как-то странно. Так бы вообще в одну строку можно было бы сделать.

Comment: @andreymal, надо отправлять в DuckDuckGo, он сразу показывает ответы со SO :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '<span class="empname11">
        <a class="empname11" href="/users/Pls" title="Дмитрий Пренов">
            here string...
        </a>
        [
        <a class="empname11" href="/users/Pls" title="Pls">
            here string...
        </a>
        ]
    </span>
    <span id="po_date_83387313">
        here string...
    </span>
    <br/>
    <div id="po_comment_83387313">
        here string...
    </div>
    <div id="po_comment_original_83387313" style="display:none;">
        here string...
    </div>';

$text = preg_replace('~<div[^>]*style="display:none;"[^>]*>.+?</div>~s', '', $text);

echo $text;
```